# Subprocess in a threading.Thread hang

Tags: python, multithreading, apache, cgi, subprocess

I can not understand why the code bellow hangs. When I run it from the console everything is fine, but when I try to run it through the browser the page hangs.
I'm using Python 2.7.2.

```python
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdout = None
        self.stderr = None
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name="snapshot",)

    def run(self):
        p = subprocess.Popen(["pwd"], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)
        p.communicate()

myThread = MyThread()
myThread.start()
myThread.join()
```

**Update**
I'm running Python with Apache as a CGI. The system on which is running is Gentoo 2.1.

I think the problem is in the Apache. Somehow it is blocking the new thread, but I'm not sure.

Comment: There is a syntax error — no ":" after class definition.

Comment: What do you mean "run it through the browser"?  If you're using a Python web framework you should specify which one and if you're running it directly or behind apache/nginx/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this with `shell=False`.

I suspect when you're running this code in your web framework you don't really have a shell and that's causing problems.

Alternatively, you can't reuse the `stdout` and `stdin` from your web servers process and by trying to do so with `subprocess.PIPE` you are causing things to hang.

I assume you don't actually need to run `pwd` and you're just using it as an example, but if you really just need `pwd` this is a needlessly complex way to do it.  Just replace this with the `os.curdir` attribute.

Comment: The "pwd" is only for test purpose. I tried to run `Popen` with `Shell=False` but with no successes. I also try to pass a file object to `stdout` and `stdin` but the file was only created without any output from the `pwd` command.